# How can i increase file tab size of sublime text 3?

Tags: windows-7, text-editors, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

i just started using sublime text3 on windows 7.The font size of file tab is too small for me.
Is there a way to change tab color to white?
How can i increase file tab size?

How can i increase file tab font size?

Answer (score 1):

Find your `<theme>.sublime-theme` file. Open it up and search for `tab_label`. The section should look something like this:

```json
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "font.size": 12, 
    "font.face": "Ubuntu"
},
```

Modify it according to your preferences and save the file. You should see the changes immediately.

To change the tab dimensions you can use the following section:

```json
{
    "class": "tabset_control",
    "tab_height": 42,
    "tab_width": 160,
    "tab_min_width": 48
},
```

Note: Larger font sizes (e.g. > 12pt on my system) will get cut off, even if the tab height is adjusted accordingly. [This is a well-known bug](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8889).

*This answer originated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648749/2037867).*